# How to change page numbers in ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

My page numbers were created according to user package `fansy`.

My page numbers look like 4.1, 4.2, 4.3 and so on.

But in the ToC it only shows 1, 2, 3, etc. Instead I would like ToC to display 4.1, 4.2, 4.3 ...

Any idea how to set up this special numbering in the ToC?

Comment: Please post a minimal compilable example showing your problem. Without code it is hard to help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: in particular, your example should tell us where to get the `fansy` package you (seem to) say you are using.